# Python Script Returning an error when trying to Obtain TFS work Items

Tags: python, tfs

I have written the following Pythin script to try and gather TFS (Team Foundation Server) work item data. Below is my script:-

```
from tfs import TFSAPI

user="andrew.xxxx"
password="xxxxxxxx"

tfsAddress = "http://man-tfsmig-1:8080/"
print(tfsAddress)

client = TFSAPI(tfsAddress, project="DefaultCollection/xxxxxxxx", user=user, password=password)

work_item = client.get_workitem(28274)
```

When I run the code I get the following error, but I do not know what the problem is:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\TFS_Release_Notes_app.py", line 13, in <module>
    work_item = client.get_workitem(28274)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tfs\connection.py", line 70, in get_workitem
    return self.get_workitems(id_, fields)[0]
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tfs\connection.py", line 80, in get_workitems
    work_items_batch_info = self.__get_workitems(work_items_batch, fields=fields, expand=expand)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tfs\connection.py", line 65, in __get_workitems
    object_class=Workitem)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tfs\connection.py", line 46, in get_tfs_object
    raw = self.rest_client.send_get(uri=uri, payload=payload, project=project)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tfs\connection.py", line 323, in send_get
    return self.__send_request('GET', uri, None, payload=payload, project=project, json=json)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tfs\connection.py", line 360, in __send_request
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 939, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: http://xxxx-xxxxx-1:8080/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems?ids=28274&$expand=all&api-version=1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

It's telling you the error: `404`, not found.

That means the URI you're providing for the API is incorrect.

It's generating this URI: `http://xxxx-xxxxx-1:8080/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems`. Validate if that is correct.

Usually, when TFS is running on port 8080 over HTTP, there's a `/tfs/` virtual directory.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the following line to authenticate:-

```
# Use NTLM authorization
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
client = TFSAPI("https://tfs.tfs.ru/tfs/", user=user, password=password, auth_type=HttpNtlmAuth)
```